# Eulerian polynomials evaluated in $-1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, generating-functions

Let

$$A_n(x):=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} x^{1+\text{des}(\sigma)}$$

where $\text{des}(\sigma)$ is the number of descents of $\sigma$. These are called the Eulerian polynomials. I need to express $A_n(-1)$  in terms of Euler numbers. This is an exercise in Stanley's combinatorics vol 1 (exercise 135 chapter 1). In the solution the author suggests using the known fact that
$$\sum_{d\geq 0} A_d(x) \frac{t^d}{d!}=\frac{1-x}{1-xe^{(1-x)t}}$$
and evaluate this equality in $x=-1$. Then the author suggests to compare the obtained expression with the Taylor-Maclaurin expansion of the tangent function.

**My attempt**

Evaluating in $x=-1$
$$\sum_{d\geq 0} A_d(-1) \frac{t^d}{d!}=\frac{2}{1+e^{2t}}$$
So
$$\sum_{d\geq 0} A_d(-1)\frac{t^d}{d!}+\left(\sum_{d\geq 0} A_d(-1)\frac{t^d}{d!}\right)\left(\sum_{j\geq 0} 2^j \frac{t^j}{j!} \right)=2$$
Equating the coefficients on both sides I get messy equations and I really don't know how to use the Taylor series of the tangent.

Answer (score 2):

We consider according to OPs calculation and formula (1.54) from *[Enumerative Combinatorics](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-i)* by R. P. Stanley the generating functions
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A(x)}&\color{blue}{:=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n(-1)\frac{x^n}{n!}}\tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{\tan x}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{2n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> The following is to show (exercise 135, chapter 1)
> \begin{align*}
> A_{n}(-1)&=\begin{cases}
> (-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}E_n\qquad&\qquad n\ \mathrm{odd}\\
> 0\qquad&\qquad n\ \mathrm{even}\\
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
> or equivalently
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A_{2n+1}(-1)}&\color{blue}{=(-1)^{n+1}E_{2n+1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 0}\tag{3}\\
> \color{blue}{A_{2n}(-1)}&\color{blue}{=0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \  n\geq 0}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}

**Case $n$ even:**

We obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 0}}&\color{blue}{A_{2n}(-1)\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(A(x)+A(-x)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}+\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}+\frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=1}
\end{align*}
and the claim (4) follows.

**Case $n$ odd:**

At first we derive a representation of the generating function with odd $A_n(-1)$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq 0}}&\color{blue}{A_{2n+1}(-1)\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(A(x)-A(-x)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{1+e^{2x}}-\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}-\frac{e^{2x}}{1-e^{2x}}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1-e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

Now we recall *[Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)*
and get
\begin{align*}
\tan x&=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}=\frac{2}{2i}\,\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}
=-i\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{e^{2ix}+1}\\
&=i\frac{1-e^{2ix}}{1+e^{2ix}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

Combining (5) and (6) we obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1-e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}}
&=-i\tan (-ix)\\
&=-i\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{2n+1}\frac{(-ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\tag{$\to\ $(2)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n\geq 0}E_{2n+1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}
\end{align*}
and the claim (3) follows.